# Interesting: comment text changed in the new inbox

Tags: support, comments, top-bar

#### Comments seem to be formatted against original text in the new top bar inbox:

[image]

Comment: Should this be tagged as [tag:bug]?

Comment: Possibly the comment was edited and the inbox isn't picking up on that. (Do you see this edit?)

Comment: I'm not sure... Perhaps it's an intended filter for stuff like +1

Comment: @michaelb958 It may have been edited, but I didn't see it. Also, I recent leant the notification system is aware of comment edits (at least when it comes to @pings).

Comment: he did edited the comment as I can see a small pen (cil?) besides the time.

Comment: @Braiam I never noticed that pencil before!

Comment: @random Now I see it's because it was edited, but I didn't realize that when I posted the question. I thought it was something like the "thank you" filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original text of that comment read,

> Also, no no no no no no

That was edited 5 seconds later to prepend the "+1" and lower-case the "A".

Although I kinda like the idea of a filter that would remove "[+-]\d" from the front of comments, nothing like this exists in the system right now. And if it did, it'd act on the actual comments, not just the inbox.

Comment: Yay, I was right!